# xtable caption alignment left aligned with table or centered (using knitr)

Tags: r, knitr, caption, xtable

I'd like to align an xtable figure caption left adjusted with the table, or if that doesn't work, at least centered, because I think it looks kind of stupid a small table being centered and the corresponding caption being left aligned. Also, left aligning both table and caption is not optimal.

It should be possible [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470306/xtable-left-just) `latex.environments = "left"`, but I get an error message, just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590261/problems-cross-referencing-in-latex-with-knitr-and-xtable) post.

I don't think the problem lies in the referencing, because I get the same error message with and without `label="myLabel"`.

Here a MWE:

```
<<table, echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
print(xtable(lm(mpg~hp, data=mtcars), caption="Linear Model", label="myLabel") , caption.placement = "top", latex.environments="left")
@
```

The error (short form, for long version see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590261/problems-cross-referencing-in-latex-with-knitr-and-xtable) post again):

```
Missing $ inserted.
Missing delimiter (. inserted)
Missing $ inserted
Missing \right. inserted
```

Does somebody know a solution? Left aligned with left side of the table or centered, I'd be happy with any solution.

Comment: I have the problem. In the meanwhile did you find out the problem using `latex.environments="left"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution to at least center the table captions, using package [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption), specifying

```
\usepackage[
    singlelinecheck=false,
    justification=centering
]{caption}
```

Comment: For left-justifying the table, use `latex.environments="flushleft"`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31898709/3625022.